# Hide HTML blocks with their respective button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I am currently learning a bit of JavaScript, and doing a project I have run into a problem. My HTML code would be something like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <button id="button1" onclick="hideBlock()">Hide Block 1</button>
  <div id="block1"></div>
  <button id="button2" onclick="hideBlock()">Hide Block 2</button>
  <div id="block2"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is that with each button I can show and hide each block. This is the JavaScript code for the first block I have written:

```
function hideBlock() {
  var block = document.getElementById("block1");   
  if (block.style.display === "none") {
    block.style.display = "block";        
  } else {
    block.style.display = "none";   
  }
}
```

And this works, but I think it is not correct to repeat the code for each block. How could I connect each button with its respective block to do everything from the same code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the adjacent block by using `nextElementSibling`, and attach the event listeners properly by using `addEventListener` instead:

```js
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <button>Hide Block 1</button>
  <div>block 1</div>
  <button>Hide Block 2</button>
  <div>block 2</div>
</div>
```